# How to set val property with Kotlin reflection?

Tags: reflection, kotlin, kotlin-reflect

I would like to return a copy of a class with a different value assigned to a `val` property.

```
data class Person(val name: String, val age: Int)

fun main() {
    val person = Person("Morné", 25)
    val property = person::class.declaredMemberProperties.first { it.name == "age" }
    person.copyWithValue(property.name, 22)
}
```

if `age` was a `var` then I could do it like follows:

```
fun main() {
    val person = Person("Morné", 25)
    val property = person::class.declaredMemberProperties.first { it.name == "age" }
    if (property is KMutableProperty<*>)
        property.setter.call(person, 22)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really want to return just a copy of the object, you can use [`copy`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html#copying), e.g.:

```
fun main() {
  val person = Person("Morné", 25)
  val newPerson = person.copy(age = 22)
}
```

Otherwise if you really must edit the `age` it must not be a `val` in the first place. Using reflection you could still adapt the value, but if the answers up to here already suffice, they are the way to go...

For a more dynamic way you can use the following (I would still target the `copy`-method, as then you wouldn't accidently update the current object):

```
val person = Person("Morné", 25)
val updates = mapOf("lastname" to "N/A", "age" to 22)

val copiedPerson = with(person::class.memberFunctions.first { it.name == "copy" }) {
  callBy(mapOf(instanceParameter!! to person)
      .plus(updates.mapNotNull { (property, newValue) ->
        parameters.firstOrNull { it.name == property }
            ?.let { it to newValue }
      })
  )
}
println(copiedPerson)
```

which prints:

```
Person(name=Morné, age=22)
```

You could also use something like `.let { person::class.cast(it }` after `callBy` if you want to continue with the actual type. If you only want this to work with the `Person` type you could also exchange `person` with `Person` and cast it directly to `as Person`.

Comment: I want a solution that does not require me to know any properties at compile time. I used age as a trivial example, my selection criteria will be more complex.

Comment: I wonder which use case would require such a construct. Until then I will prepare for an update of the answer ;-)

Comment: Updated the answer... let me know if that helps you... or if you have questions..

Comment: Wow, StackOverflow at its best: Yes, one should never use reflection if it's avoidable, but there are legitimate use cases anyway.

Answer (score 0):

As always, reflection should be used with care, as it undermines the assumptions taken by the compiler. However, if you do need to modify a `val` and you don't have the luxury of a `data class` (hence, no `copy` method), you will need to resort to using kotlin-java-reflection:

```kotlin
class Person(val name: String, val age: Int)

fun main() {
    val person = Person("Morné", 25)
    val property = person::class.memberProperties.first { it.name == "age" }
    val javaField = property.javaField!!
    javaField.isAccessible = true
    javaField.set(person, 32)
    println(person.age)
}
```

This prints `32`.

However, this will only work on Kotlin/JVM.